# fix internal padding of Textfield in Jetpack compose Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I want to remove internal padding of textfield which is blocking my text appearance

[image]

```
TextField(
    value = Dishcount,    
    onValueChange = { 
       if (it.text.isNotEmpty()) {
          val userInput = it.text.toIntOrNull()
          userInput?.let { input ->                
              if (input > 0) {
                  Dishcount = it                    
                  Dish.count = input
              } 
              else {

              }
           } ?: run {            }
} else {

        }
    },    
    keyboardOptions = 
       KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardTypeKeyboardType.Number),    
    modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp).fillMaxHeight(),
    colors = 
       TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent),    
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 15.sp)
)
```

tried `modifier.padding(0.dp)`  but not able to remove it

Comment: Can we see a picture? or screenshot?

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLMPR.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your own `TextField`, you should use `BasicTextField` instead. Like example:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = "ahsdjh kajhdash adhasd hasjdhkasdklajsdklajsdjkla",
    onValueChange = {},
    Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .width(50.dp)
        .background(Color.Magenta)
)
```

[image]